# Why does TClientDataSet get the wrong type for WideText fields?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, delphi-xe

I'm working with a service with Delphi XE and I receive a ClientDataset from a client. When I check the type of a field that is ftWideText, the system detects that the field is ftBlob. To understand the reason, I have saved the ClientDataset to a file and I get XML with an error with the definition of this field. I get:

```xml
<FIELD attrname="TEXTTEST" fieldtype="bin.hex" SUBTYPE="" SUBTYPE="WideText" />
```

The attribute SUBTYPE appears twice when the correct is:

```xml
<FIELD attrname="TEXTTEST" fieldtype="bin.hex" SUBTYPE="WideText" />
```

This problem only appears over a server; the others work OK. I don't know where the problem is, if it's Delphi, ADO, SQL Server.

If I change the Web service to another computer using the same database, all works OK. I think that it is an ADO problem with the components installed on the computer.

**Update:** I have the same problem with Windows 2003 Server computers. Two computers with MDAC 2.8 SP2 (ODBC components version 3.526) and both fails. I installed Microsoft SQLServer 2008 R2 to one of the computers and the problem is fixed. I need to know what is installed or reinstalled with SqlServer2008 to fix the problem. Apparently is related with ADO but now I have two machines with the same version of ADO and only one fails.

Comment: Does the server support Unicode strings? If yes, are the fields declared as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem isn't related with Microsoft MDAC ADO Components. The problem was that the computers with this problem had al old version of Midas.dll. That dll is related with the Delphi ClientDataset. The problem was fixed replacing server Midas.dll with the same version of the client.

Answer (score 1):

Definitevilly the problem was related with ADO components. The version of the components was 6.0, upgrading to 6.1 the problem is solved.